# How do I see the actual filepath that nginx is trying to access for a file?

Tags: nginx

Right now I've got Nginx setup to serve what I'm pretty sure is a valid filepath. However, it's giving me a 404 not found.

I've looked in `/var/log/nginx/access.log` and it shows me:

```
[05/Oct/2016:19:15:50 -0500] "GET /menu.html HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ....
```

But not what path it was trying to access on localhost, which should be `/usr/share/nginx/html/menu.html`. How do I configure Nginx to show me this information?

Comment: have You tried log_format directive with defining $request_filename attribute? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: @num8er that does it. None of my google searches turned up that option - post it as an answer and I can accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend to try `log_format` directive with `$realpath_root` (or `$document_root`) and  `$request_filename` attribute.

Read this documentations and customize Your logs as You wish:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '--> "$request_filename" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

Comment: For anyone else from the future, here's the simple two lines I added to the top of my .conf to get the path info desired.

log_format foo '[$time_local] "$request" Status code:$status; Filepath: $request_filename';
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log foo;

Answer (score 0):

I believe the full path is shown in the error_log file for a 404.

Example:

2017/02/10 12:20:45 [error] : *239 open() "/usr/local/files/myFile.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: myserver.com, request: "GET /path/to/myFile.js HTTP/1.1", host: "myserver.com", referrer: "http://myserver.com/home"