# Serve media files from outside the Django-project-folder with Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, django-deployment

I'm trying to serve in production (not development) media files for my Django-project with a Nginx-server. The media-files are not located within the django-folder.

The folder structure is like:

```
|- django_user
|     |- media
|     |- Myproject
|          |- static
|          |- myproject
|               |- settings.py
```

**Nginx-Server**:

```
upstream websocket{
        server 127.0.0.1:6379;
}
server {
    server_name myproject.com;

    client_max_body_size 5M;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django_user/Myproject;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/django_user/media;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myproject.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myproject.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }

}
server {
    if ($host = myproject.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name myproject.com
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Here is a part of my **settings.py**:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/django_user/media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Saving files in the media folder is working. I've set up an image field like this:

```
myicon = models.ImageField(default="static/images/default_icon.png" , blank=True, upload_to="images/")
```

I've checked it and the images (e.g. test.png) are correctly saved in /home/django_user/media/images. My problem is that the images in the media-folder cannot be shown on my website (myproject.com/images/test.png), it always shows me:

```
Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.
```

I've done already *"manage.py collectstatic"*, and static files are loaded correctly. Only the media-files are not found.

I've also tried the following variations of my nginx-server, all without success:

```
location /media/ {
     root /home/django_user;
}

location /media {
     root /home/django_user/media/;
}

location /media {
     root /home/django_user/;
}

location /media/ {
    alias /home/django_user/media/;
}
```

Can you help me with this problem? What am I missing here or where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) method:

```
location /media/ {
    alias /home/django_user/media/;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But it did not help... I will update my tried variations in my post with your proposal.

Comment: @Charbacca then look deeper into your `access.log` and `error.log`, what was the path nginx tried to find `test.png`?

Comment: error.log doesn't say anything regarding test.png and access.log says "GET /images/test.png HTTP/1.1" 404 159

Comment: @Charbacca try to change your `access.log` format as said here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885617/how-do-i-see-the-actual-filepath-that-nginx-is-trying-to-access-for-a-file to be able to get actual local path nginx tries to access

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying with the wrong URL.

If you define:

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/` and `location /media/`

Then the URL should be `myproject.com/media/images/test.png` instead of `myproject.com/images/test.png` in both scenarios (development and production)